# Cardinality of powers of infinite sets

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, infinity, ordinals

How to prove that for infinite sets $S,S'$-
(i) If $|S'|<|S|$, then $|S^{S'}|=|S|$?
(ii) If $|S'|=|S|$, then $|S^{S'}|=|2^S|$?
Also what is $|S^{S'}|$ when $|S'|>|S|$?

Comment: Doesn't (i) imply continuum hypothesis? As in $|Q|<|S|\implies |R|=|S|$

Comment: Relatively few things can be proved in ZFC about cardinal exponentiation, but one of those things is that $(\aleph_\omega)^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: @Akababa Not only that; it implies everything else too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This one isn't true. Indeed, assuming Choice, for any infinite cardinal $\kappa$, we have $\kappa < \kappa^{\text{cf}(\kappa)}$ (this follows immediately from König's theorem), where $\text{cf}$ is cofinality. So let $S$ be any set of singular cardinality $\kappa$, and $S'$ be a set of cardinality equal to $\kappa$'s cofinality.
2. Under the axiom of choice, $$2^\kappa \leq \kappa^\kappa \leq (2^{\kappa})^\kappa = 2^{\kappa \times \kappa} = 2^\kappa$$ so equality holds throughout and $2^\kappa = \kappa^\kappa$. Note, however, that this is pretty much the best that we can say about $2^{\kappa}$: Easton's theorem states strongly that the operation $\kappa \mapsto 2^{\kappa}$ is basically not restricted at all in ZFC on the regular cardinals beyond the simple requirements of monotonicity, Cantor's theorem, and König's lemma.
3. When $\kappa > \lambda$, then $2^\kappa \leq \lambda^\kappa \leq \kappa^\kappa = 2^\kappa$, so $\lambda^\kappa = 2^\kappa$.

Note that in general, cardinal exponentiation is pretty much unspecified in ZFC. However, *in the presence of the generalised continuum hypothesis*, cardinal exponentiation is extremely precisely specified, and I'll give its behaviour here to demonstrate "the neatest thing you could possibly hope for". These are proved by much the same circular-inequality method as Point 2 above.

- If $\lambda < \text{cf}(\kappa)$, then $\kappa^\lambda = \kappa$. (Here, $\text{cf}$ is the cofinality.)
- If $\text{cf}(\kappa) \leq \lambda \leq \kappa$, then $\kappa^\lambda = \kappa^+$.
- If $\kappa < \lambda$, then $\kappa^\lambda = \lambda^+$.

Comment: I heard from John that I am supposed to insult you...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, I believe I'm supposed to insult you too :)

Comment: I think the third part of your answer needs modification. If $\kappa\ge \lambda$ then $2^\kappa \le \lambda^\kappa \le \kappa^\kappa = 2^\kappa$.

Comment: Huh. Of course. Thanks!